# UWP app database. Will the user need to install mongodb separately or it can be packaged?

Tags: c#, database, uwp, nosql, desktop-application

I have never packaged a windows app before and have always used database as a service (e. firebase , mongodb, MS SQL Server).
I need my UWP desktop application to work without internet (always) and therefore looking for most suitable database. I prefer noSql database, however, can go with SQL based database if really needed.
My question is: when the user will download UWP app from microsoft store, what will he need to do for the app to work. Is mongodb packaged with the app? so when he downloads the app from store, the app will just work?
Database Requirements:
1- no extra installation steps. User downloads app from store and it works
2- allows adding listeners so apps will not need to poll for data
3- offline (not cloud based)
4- preferably noSQL
5- no complex/custom steps to make it work with UWP desktop app

Thanks in advance in helping me choose best database solution for my scenario

Comment: I would have a look at SQLite... Its not noSQL but it is Microsofts preferred option for a local, portable database that doesn't require any installation. Its also multiplatform and can be used on pretty much any mobile/desktop OS

Comment: You can install from [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite) and use [these docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sqlite-databases) to setup in UWP

Comment: Thanks Glynn for quick reply. During google search i came across SQLite as a popular database for my purpose. However, as u mentioned it is not noSQL. Therefore i wanted to know if there was a different choice. I wanted more clarity on "does installation package take care of installing mongodb or database as well or user will need to download database installer separately"?  Also, does SQLite allow adding listeners for changes or apps will need to poll for data? please note i want this data to be shared between multiple apps. My UWP app is with desktop extension. UWP app starts a console app.

Comment: Yes there are a number of different alternatives e.g. [Unqlite](https://unqlite.org) or [LiteDB](https://www.litedb.org). I haven't had any experience with them myself though. For your purpose, I'd say you should be looking at a portable database as they don't require any installation and as long as you include the libraries in your release, they should work on any machine. If you do want to package a full-blown DB engine service (eg MongoDB)  then you absolutely can include this in an installer, although in most cases, it won't automatically be included so you'll have to set that up manually.

Comment: ok thanks alot. i do want listeners. i will look into gRPC (it is also portable like sqlite?)